# How do I replace 'string1' with 'string2' if line contains 'string3' in Notepad++?

Tags: regex, replace, notepad++

I have the following contents in the file:

```
This is line one
This is line two with string1 and string3
This is line three with string3
```

I need to replace 'string1' with 'string2' if the line contains 'string3', so that the result would be:

```
This is line one
This is line two with string2 and string3
This is line three with string3
```

Comment: @wiktor stribizew, This is not duplicate of 'Regex: Remove lines containing'. I do not want to remove lines.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The approach may be, but if there is someone out there trying to find a solution to the problem I am facing, they will not be searching for 'remove lines containing'.

Comment: Ok, so what is your problem? Where are you stuck? Also, you have not explained *where* the `string3` may appear. From your examples, it seems that `string3` should *follow* `string2, is that so?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: I agree with Starfish, this is not *an exact duplicate of an existing question*...

Comment: @Starfish: Try this, it worked for me on notepad++ : https://regex101.com/r/4L5Wyx/1

Comment: @Gawil Thank you, that worked for me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace *all occurrences* of `string1` on any line that contains `string3` *anywhere* on that line, you need to use a `\G` based regex:

```
(?:\G(?!^)|^(?=.*string3)).*?\Kstring1
```

Replace with `string2`. See the [regex demo online](https://regex101.com/r/lLnh5s/1).

**Details**:

- `(?:\G(?!^)|^(?=.*string3))` - either the end of the previous match or a start of a line that contains `string3` in it
- `.*?` - any 0+ chars other than line breaks
- `\K`  - a match reset operator discarding all the text matched so far in the current iteration
- `string1` - a `string1` substring to be replaced.

The following text

```
This is line string1
This is line two with string1 and string3 string1
This is line two with string1 string1 and string3 
This is line three with string3
This is line string3 with string1 and string1
```

turns into

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the answer

Answer (score 0):

On behalf of @Gawil

On Notepad++ Go to Search->Replace

Under 'Find what': `^(?=.*?string3)(.*?)string1(.*?)$`

Under 'Replace with': `\1string2\2`

Perform 'Replace' or 'Replace All' as necessary.
[image]

Comment: This way, you only replace *one occurrence* of `string1`. See my answer showing how to replace all occurrences of the word on a line containing `string3`.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew yeah, I had to do multiple clicks on 'Replace All'

Comment: @Starfish: Sorry, I did not anticipate that there could be multiple occurences of string1 in a line